# How to find the total gain for a particular gain stage

Tags: gain, vacuum-tube

Can someone help me how to calculate the total voltage gain for this particular gain stage?

[image: 1st gain stage]

As you can see, there are five resistors. They are R3, R4, R5, R6 and R7. R4(100k) is the load resistor and R3(1k) is the cathode resistor. Calculate both of them, we get 37.95 V which is 31.58 dB and the output impedance is 62.05. Notice that the capacitor is not used. Now, we will calculate both the impedance and another resistor which is R5 (360k). 360/(360+62.05) will be 0.85 V which is - 1.4 dB. 31.58 db - 1.4 dB is 30.18 dB. This is excluding the other resistors, R6 (180k) and R7 (33k). Using the same formula x÷(y+x) which is 33÷(180+33) will be 0.15 V which is - 16.5 dB. If we calculate the previous gain value which is 30.18 dB - 16.5 dB it will be 13.68 dB.

So the loaded gain for the first stage will be 13.68 dB. Is my calculation correct?

Comment: Where are you assuming the output to be?

Comment: R4 might look like a load resistor, but it's not the anode load resistance. That's R4 // R5 // (R6+R7). With R3 to that giving you the valve gain, you then apply the R6/7 voltage divider to that to get the gain into pin 7.

Comment: So, R4÷R5÷(R6+R7) = 100k÷360k÷(180k+33k)=0.27÷(180k+33k)=0.001? Is that correct?

Comment: // means 'in parallel with' in the context of resistors

Comment: Sorry Neil my English is not good but what does that means? How to form the calculation formula?

Comment: Wait, is it 78÷(180+33)=0.3? I really have no clue.

Comment: Or is it, 1/100+1/360=0.012 then 1/0.012 will be 83.3? I really have no clue, my math skills are bad.

Comment: If I calculate both 83.3 and the cathode resistor which is the R3 (1k) then I get 33.75 V or 30.57 dB. Is this the voltage gain?

Comment: `Or is it, 1/100+1/360=0.012 then 1/0.012 will be 83.3? ` Right process to get the parallel resistance, but wrong answer (maybe just not keeping enough significant figures) for those two resistors, it's 78.3. However, you have to include the R5+R6 resistance of 213 k in the sum as well, to give a total load of 57.2. Do you see how they load the anode as well?

Comment: So, 57.2 convert to dB will be 35.1 dB. And this is the loaded gain for the first stage, isn't it? Right before you responded, another calculation comes to mind. I thought it was 1/100 +1/360 +1/213=0.017. Then, 1/0.017 will be 58.82 V. Convert 58.82 to dB will be 35.4 dB. It is not that far

Comment: Because as you previously said the R4 (100k) is actually not the anode load resistor, which one of those resistors actually presents as the load resistor for the anode/plate?

Comment: Your use of the symbol V is a little disconcerting. When calculating the anode load resistance, the figure should be in ohms. When calculating the gain of the valve, the figure is a pure number, a ratio, though admittedly some people write it as V/V in data sheets. The only difference between 57.2 and 58.82 is the number of significant figures you kept. It's inappropriate to discard so many during the calculation that you get the wrong answer, and then express the answer to too many digits. Better to do a full precision calculation, then truncate the answer.

Comment: Yes, it is because of these V/V figures in spec sheets that make me wrote these resistors in V. Sorry for that, Neil.

Comment: The anode load is R4 in parallel with R5 in parallel with R6+R7 (and all in parallel with the output impedance of the valve itself, which is ideally infinity, in practice is very high, but might not be completely negligible with respect to 57.2 k). So R4 forms most of the anode load, but you get an error of almost 2:1 if you assume it's the only load.

Comment: I see. So the formula to calculate the next stage will be the same, which is 1/? + 1/? + 1/?. Correct?